¿Como cambiar el nombre de los valores en una segmentación de datos en power Bi?
Tengo una segmentacion de datos en power bi con dos valores 0 y 1, quiero cambiar el texto visual a verdadero y falso sin que el valor del 0 y 1 cambie, ¿como se puede hacer?

Puedes crear una nueva columna con los textos, por ejemplo, valiéndote de Switch:
NuevaColumna = SWITCH([OtraColumna],0,"falso",1,"verdadero")


¿No se podría hacer sin añadir una columna solo cambiando lo visual de la segmentación?

No me considero experto en PowerBI, hasta donde entiendo, no se puede cambiar solo la representación visual.

Si no quieres modificar la Tabla origen, la solución es algo más compleja e implica:

Hacer una tabla del tipo valor/texto, para traducir los 1 y 0 en un "Si" o un "No"
Plantear una relación entre la tabla origen y la nueva

Para crear la nueva tabla, vas a la solapa "Modelado" y haces click en "Tabla" y puedes por agregar el siguiente código DAX para definirla
SiNo = 
    UNION(
        ROW("Valor", 1, "Texto", "Si"),
        ROW("Valor", 0, "Texto", "No")
    )

Luego restaría ir a la vista de Modelo y creas la relación:

Y ahora tendrías la tabla "SiNo" que puedes trasladar como objeto visual que sirva como selector. Honestamente la solución de jachguate me parece mejor.
